# Moving the Windows installer folder to a network share drive?

Tags: windows-7, windows

My tiny SSD drive really needs some space; the installer folder ate up 5 GB. After research over the Internet I found talk about moving it to a different local drive.

**Question:** Can I move the Windows Installer folder to a network drive?

I'd like to understand any common issues I may have but I am fine if I can only "repair" installations when I'm connected to company network, but I'm unsure if this will cause any other problem and make my system inoperable for any reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Warning:** *I don't think this would cause any immediate problems, but you should backup your system and test beforehand just to be safe.*

In a perfect world, you would **not** want to do this (move or delete the installer folder) or you'd do it at your own risk; so again, backup, test, and read up on the ramifications of doing this ***at your own risk***—see other options below for quick Windows 7 cleanup that I used to use all the time but scripted it out with a bunch of other things.

When you manage hundred of PCs and have backup images, etc. in a business environment, the risk isn't such a big deal but for home usage and your backup strategies, it may be a different story. I never have moved the Installer folder in my environment but that's the best practice strategy I'd take if the below options don't help first and you **must**.  There are also some [`DISM`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14) commands you could run for further cleanup but start with the basics first.

---

### Doing It

If you decide to move the Windows Installer folder, you'll probably want to create a symbolic link pointing to the new location.

**Mklink Command (run as administrator)**

- `MKLINK /J "C:\Windows\Installer" "D:\New folder path location"`

---

### Quick Cleanup Methods

1. > [**Use Disk Cleanup**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17421/windows-free-up-drive-space#delete-files-using-disk-cleanup=windows-vista)
   >
   > Cleaning out your PC on a regular basis frees up drive space and helps
   >   it run better. One of the easiest ways to clean up files you no longer
   >   need is by using Disk Cleanup.
   >
   > 1. Open Disk Cleanup by clicking the **Start** button [image] In the search box,
   >      type **Disk Cleanup**, and then, in the list of results, select **Disk
   >      Cleanup**.
   > 2. If prompted, select the drive that you want to clean up, and then
   >      select **OK**.
   > 3. In the **Disk Cleanup** dialog box in the Description section, select
   >      **Clean up system files**.
   > 4. If prompted, select the drive that you want to clean up, and then
   >      select **OK**.
   > 5. In the **Disk Cleanup** dialog box, on the **Disk Cleanup** tab, select the
   >      check boxes for the file types that you want to delete, and then
   >      select **OK**. To remove data from a previous installation of Windows,
   >      select the **Previous Windows installation(s)** check box.
   > 6. In the message that appears, select **Delete files**.
   > 7. Go back to **Computer** in File Explorer, select the drive you cleaned
   >      up, and then select **Refresh**. If you need to free more space (the
   >      drive is still marked red), go to the next tip.
2. > **Commands to Run As Administrator**
   >
   > - `VSSADMIN RESIZE SHADOWSTORAGE /FOR=C: /ON=C: /MAXSIZE=1GB`
   > - `POWERCFG HIBERNATE OFF`
   > - `CLEANMGR /D c: /SAGESET:100`
   > - `CLEANMGR /SAGERUN:100`

---

### Further Resources

- [Can Windows Installer Files be moved or deleted from the Windows Directory?](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-performance/can-windows-installer-files-be-moved-or-deleted/ae72920d-b86a-4e43-b78a-55eee9c9be3f)
- [Symbolic Links in Windows for Pointing a Folder to Another Folder on an External Hard Drive or SSD](http://skimfeed.com/blog/symbolic-links-in-windows-for-pointing-a-folder-to-another-folder-on-an-external-hard-drive-or-ssd/)
- [MKLink](https://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html)
- [Tips to free up drive space on your PC](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17421/windows-free-up-drive-space#delete-files-using-disk-cleanup=windows-vista)
- [DISM Image Management Command-Line Options](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14)
- [VSSADMIN](https://ss64.com/nt/vssadmin.html)